# Open new tab on document ready with dynamic url's

Tags: jquery

I have a div which is getting populated with links(urls) on key up(live event/ajax). I want to op all the links in this specific div in a new tab, so I tried:

```
$("#div a").attr("target","_blank");
```

I placed this in document ready and in the live.key up, doesn't work. What else can I try?

Comment: If that div got 100 links, that'll popup 100 new tabs / windows ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [window.open](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) instead. Note that almost all browsers by default doesn't allow to open new tabs without clicking by user. It's called pop-up windows blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind this question...silly me...I just had to put it in the ajax request...